# Seeking Building Shapefiles in New South Wales, Australia

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, buildings

[image]

Is there a website with a comprehensive source for Building Shapefiles in New South Wales, Australia?

I have downloaded the Shapefile from here https://download.geofabrik.de/australia-oceania.html however there are a lot of buildings missing (see image)

Comment: https://osmbuildings.org/ ?

Comment: Duplicate of below q which now has an answer
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/can-anyone-recommend-a-comprehensive-site-to-find-building-shapefiles-for-sydney/18165#18165